# archive warning: he bundle itunessoftwareservice could not be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources

Tags: xcode4.3, app-store-connect, application-loader

while trying to archive for submission I am getting this warning, if I try to do the validation or distribution, they hang. I am using Xcode4.3.2
The msg below suggests: try reinstalling the bundle - how to do that?
I did not find any useful suggestion among the existing posts

> 2012-07-14 14:15:00.935 Validation[1884:f07] Could not load framework
>   at
>   “file://localhost/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application%20Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/”
>   (err = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle
>   “ITunesSoftwareService” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or
>   missing necessary resources."
>   (dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
>   Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService):
>   Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ITunesConnectFoundation
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
>   Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService
>   Reason: image not found) UserInfo=0x400419fe0
>   {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary
>   resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the
>   bundle.,
>   NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
>   Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService,
>   NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
>   Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService):
>   Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ITunesConnectFoundation
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
>   Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService
>   Reason: image not found,
>   NSBundlePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
>   Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “ITunesSoftwareService” couldn’t be
>   loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.})
>   warning: Application validation was skipped.

Comment: Sounds like a slightly corrupt install of Xcode and some of the related libraries/frameworks, or a file read issue. You may also consider updating to the current latest version at time of writing, which is v4.3.3

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. I think it has something to do with the new update because after allowing it to happen everything worked fine. Regards,

Comment: Happy to hear it's all sorted for you now :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like re-installing xcode (or upgrading it) fixes the problem. Still puzzled why did it happen. I have ignored the offer to upgrade postponing it until the submission is done for few days, maybe Apple changed some links as it refers to itunes bundle? Anyhow it works now.